# logout from facebook completely

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I have integrated facebook SDK and able to login to facebook. If user is enabled with facebook account on iOS settings then it ask for permission to acces in app otherwise it goes to safari for facebook login and come back to app. For logout I used following code:

```
NSHTTPCookie *cookie;
NSHTTPCookieStorage *storage = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];

for (cookie in [storage cookies])
{
    NSString* domainName = [cookie domain];
    NSRange domainRange = [domainName rangeOfString:@"facebook"];
    if(domainRange.length > 0)
    {
        [storage deleteCookie:cookie];
    }
}
   [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
```

But it is unable to logout completely. If  I again click the login button it still showing access token as well as not moving to safari for facebook login again it means it has not logged out completely from facebook. I am unable to recognized the issue. If anyone know about this please help me out.

I would be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using version 3.x of the Facebook SDK for iOS? If so, the FBSession class should have a method called

```
-[FBSession closeAndClearTokenInformation]
```

Hopefully this will work for you.